# Black screen when pressing Home button

Tags: android, android-service

I get a weird bug after restart, when i turn screen off and on, pressing the home button results in black screen and i need to restart to have control over my phone again.

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to know when the screen goes off and on to do some logic.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF")) {
            if (context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SETTING_PREFERENCE, 0)
                    .getBoolean(Constant.SETTING_LOCKSCREEN_STATUS, false)) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
                intent1.addFlags(0x10000000);
                context.startActivity(intent1);
            }

        } else {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON")) {
                if (context
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constant.SETTING_PREFERENCE, 0)
                        .getBoolean(Constant.SETTING_LOCKSCREEN_STATUS, false)) {
                    (new Intent(context, TestActivity.class))
                            .addFlags(0x10000000);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
                if (context
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constant.SETTING_PREFERENCE, 0)
                        .getBoolean(Constant.SETTING_LOCKSCREEN_STATUS, false)) {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,
                            TestActivity.class);
                    intent2.addFlags(0x10000000);
                    context.startActivity(intent2);
                }
                return;
            }
        }
```

I can sometimes reproduce this bug and from logcat i can see: `Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord` but the service is running. Not sure how to tackle this situation.

Comment: Did you write that code trying to fix the problem, or do you only have the problem when you are using that code? What is that code doing exactly?

Comment: I made the modification in the code to start the activity. It's the same situation. My scope is to start an activity after reboot, and on screen is on(if it was off). On nexus(android 5) i have this problem, on samsung what i tested so far it's ok.

Comment: i am starting to think it's related to SmartLock (i disabled it and the problem does not appear now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created this intent but didn't start it. This code has no effect:

```
                (new Intent(context, TestActivity.class))
                        .addFlags(0x10000000);
```

Comment: Yes, my bad. I changed and started the activity there too. It's the same situation.

Comment: i cannot reproduce the problem again. so i accepted the answer as the correct one. thx.